# nothing works after upgrading tensorflow

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

Win7-64, Python 3.6.
After upgrading tensorflow to 1.8,
following text

```
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello))
```

gives errors:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 978, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 961, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 648, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 560, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 922, in
>   create_module   File "", line 205, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "K:\Python\testTensorflow.py", line 1, in 
>       import tensorflow as tf   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in
>   
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line
>   49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 14, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 978, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 961, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 648, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 560, in module_from_spec
>   File "", line 922, in
>   create_module   File "", line 205, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed ImportError: DLL load failed with error code -1073741795
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in   from
>   tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File
>   "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 16, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal')   File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126,
>   in import_module  return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package,
>   level) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
>   '_pywrap_tensorflow_internal'
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. Performing the below steps solved this issue:

- `pip uninstall tensorflow`
- `pip install tensorflow`

You may also try:

- `conda install tensorflow`  (If you have anaconda installed)